# Sqlite Database Still Exists Even I Clear Data and Delete the App from 6.0.1 Device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow

My db implementation is something like this

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static DbHelper mDbHelper;
    private Context context;

    public static synchronized DbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mDbHelper == null) {
            checkDataBase(context);
            mDbHelper = new DbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            Log.d(log, context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        }

        return mDbHelper;
    }

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

I put some initial data on `onCreate` method from an excel file. When I install my app from Android Studio after I cleared data and deleted the app, I behaves like there is a database and never calls `onCreate` method. It also brings my old data from the old excel file. DB must be deleted when I clear the data.

I log the path in Logcat and it says: `/data/user/0/com.mypackage.app/databases/dbname`

I think there is a cache holding the database alive somewhere in my device. It occurs only on my 6.0.1 device. It works fine on 5.1.1

Any advices to delete the database?

Comment: I too have noticed this on occasion on my nexus 6P, to get around the issue I reboot the phone after uninstalling and then it does not have the data anymore

Comment: Ouch! My problem solved also by rebooting. But I look forward to know If some of my users face this issue when they updated to new version? :(

Comment: when updating app, this is done automatically, you just have to  increase the `db_version`, which leads to fire `onUpgrade()` where you can do whatever you want to the current **database, add/edit/delete rows, tables** ...

Comment: I already done that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem too, and it bothered me for an entire day.

Uninstall the app then restart the phone. That solves the problem on Marshmellow.